# Java Swing set "actual" Frame size (inside)

Tags: java, swing, frame

I have a JFrame which contains just one JPanel.
I have tried setting the Panel's size and packing the frame, but that has no effect.

If I set the JFrame's size, it will change the size so it includes the title bar and borders.
How do I set the "actual size" so it doesn't include the title bar and borders?

Example:

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance, guys

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could set the contentPane's preferredSize and call pack on the JFrame, but in general it's usually best to let components size themselves based on their preferred sizes as determined by their layout managers.

Comment: Yeah, but this is an app with just a panel where graphics will be drawn, so the size has to be very accurate.

Answer (score 12):

This is an example of setting JPanel's size and packing the frame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Did you try something like this?

Comment: Yep, thats what hovercraft-full-of-eels said, works fine indeed.

Comment: I only saw him post once I have sent mine :)

Comment: No problem mate, I upvoted yours as well :) even though I had already figured it out this time, sometimes I really can't do without an example :)

Comment: kleopatra the same code doesn't works with setSize instead of setPreferredSize, but if you know how to fix plz tell us

Answer (score 10):

If you set the preferred size of the JPanel then the JFrame's pack() method will respect it.

Comment: yep, since I assume it's being added to the contentPane's BorderLayout.CENTER position -- but if something else is being added to another BorderLayout position, it will mess things up.

Comment: @Andrew, sorry, I'm making a lot of assumptions, but assuming the OP wants to set the gui size excepting borders, menus, etc, if one only sizes the BorderLayout.CENTER component and adds other components to other BorderLayout positions, then the ultimate GUI size can be wrong.  But my assumptions were incorrect since the OP is mainly interested in the size of a component that holds an image. So Vincent is indeed correct, and I will delete my first comment to him shortly (and this comment to you).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `.getInsets` method on `JFrame` which gives you the dimensions of the sizes around the non-client area.

Then add it up to your wanted size, and set the size using `setSize`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get Frame border then first use **pack** on your frame and after that get Frame **Insets** like in this code bellow:

```
frame.pack();
Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
int frameLeftBorder = insets.left;
int frameRightBorder = insets.right;
int frameTopBorder = insets.top;
int frameBottomBorder = insets.bottom;
```

Is better to use the **pack** method right after your **setResizable(boolean)** method, because resizable for some reason changes your frame borders, but if you dont use resize method then use **pack** method right on the start of frame constructor.

Comment: Whoa 2 downvotes in a short time, looks it does not even worth to help people.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the actual size of the usable space in JFrame could be done through setting the preferred size of the container in 
`createComponents(Container container)` method. Done in this way, you skip setting the size of 
the whole JFrame through `setPreferredSize(new Dimension (width, length)` in the `run()` method. So, the code will look like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    // other code ...
    this.createCompoents(frame.getContentPane());
}

private void createCompoents(Container container) {
   // other code ...
   container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, length));
}
```